# javascript interval prevents clicking on elements (sometimes)

Tags: javascript, ajax, intervals

I don't think this is necessarily the intervals fault but this is what's happening.

Basically, I built my own "google search" function for this section of the site. It's going to list a bunch of ticket type items and the search function allows them to search the tickets just like you would in Google. As you type it populates the search you're doing.

So, interval event is continuously running and calls an AJAX function (which obviously calls a .jsp file which runs a method I coded to search the database based on the inputted text) and the returned data is then split and pasted onto the web page, you know, standard AJAX stuff.

But, when I attempt to click on one of the links, it seems to *ignore it* It's like I have to click it at a certain time to get the page to register the click. I can slow down the interval and it alleviates the issue some but then the searching seems *slow*. And it still occasionally ignores the clicks. The links are standard  links inside a table  element.

AJAX Function - I formatted the data before sending back (I prefer Java coding to JavaScript so I did it there instead XD)

The interval is set at 500MS. So it's replacing the text all at once and not row by row. So idk why it's doing this : / I don't have this issue on the other page that uses a continuous interval. Though, that page doesn't have an AJAX call.

```
function getResults(supplier, request, cat, type, displayFiles, input)
{

    var output;
    //Ajax variable
    var xmlhttp;
            //Makes the call to the ajax engine based on browser
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }  

            var url = "getResults.jsp?supplier=" + encodeURIComponent(supplier) + "&request= " + encodeURIComponent(request) + "&cat= " + encodeURIComponent(cat) + "&type= " + encodeURIComponent(type)
            + "&displayFiles= " + encodeURIComponent(displayFiles) + "&input= " + encodeURIComponent(input);                        



            xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);


            //Handling of the ajax call
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){             
                        output = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        //alert(output); //Gives the success or failure of the ajax call            
                        document.getElementById("resultsBox").innerHTML = output;

                    }
                }       

          xmlhttp.send(null); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a timer created by setInterval which is firing the search method every (at least) 500ms.

The search method is Async, so you can fire new search requests even before the old ones got completed, this can create a sequence of updates to the innerHTML properties (depending on the response time of the server) overflowing it. Because even though the request is fired every 500ms you don't know when the response will arrive.

As a suggestion, try to redo the logic, replacing setInterval by setTimeout(or even the requestAnimationFrame) to avoid the "overflow" behavior and not updating the whole results block just the new ones.

Comment: I COULD do that but I'm unsure of the implications of doing more checks as I have no idea how many tickets will be on this database at once. So, if they get it to a large amount, checking to see if the ticket is already displayed could start causing some lag issues. There would be a lot of splits and comparisons going on to do that. I figured out a work around but your suggestion on WHY it's doing it seems to make sense. I'm simply going to kill the interval when there's no focus on the input box.

Comment: Seems this was it. If the search input got beyond a certain point (slow server) it would begin to overlap the search (continuous changing of the page). Killing the interval occasionally relieves the issue. Also slightly increased the interaval as the user can theoretically never "lose focus" on the search box (use mouse wheel to scroll so they never actually click off of it). So, your solution would be cleaner but I only have a week left (I'm an intern) and just need to get this working reasonably. Along with other stuff. No time to implement your solution, sadly.

Comment: What you could do, besides check if the tickets are already displayed is keep an information, for example the ID of the last item listed, and query the database only for items older than that ID

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the way I do for games.

```
search() {
    do stuff
    setTimeout(search,500);
}
```

This is how I do continuous loops in javascript. this way it is just a loop. setTimeout runs it's function just once. setInterval runs it every interval, and it's real easy to be careless with it. With setTimeout, you let the search() function call it self again when it is done.